# How can I stop and restart observable in RxJava 2?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

Well, I have to stop emitting when the user stops the service, and I need to restart it when the user starts the service. So unsubscribing is not a good idea in this case...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think unsubscribing is a bad thing?

Comment: Because I use my observable as a service provider. I would like to stop the service when the user leave the activity, and restart it when they return.

Comment: It still isn't clear. You can unsubscribe without damaging anything, I can assure you.